# Safari CMD+Click link new tab focus

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

Is there a way to force focus to a new tab in safari when you cmd+click on links in google search results for example?

Comment: If you want even more options than what Safari has built-in, I highly recommend LinkThing which you can find at http://canisbos.com/linkthing (along with several other handy extensions). It does 2  things I love: #1) lets me set per-site preferences for where links open (new tabs or same tab) so, for example, Google Search results always open in new tabs without me having to cmd-click on them. #2) it re-writes Google search results links so they are actual links instead of links to Google which redirect you. Much easier to copy/paste the URL if that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Preferences → Tabs and enable When a new tab or window opens, make it active.

[image]

Enabling this option switches the shift modifier to disabling this functionality rather than enabling it.

Answer (score 4):

Command-Shift-click takes you to the newly-opened tab.