# Automatically make Safari active when link is clicked from Teams

Tags: macos, safari, ventura, ms-teams

Prior to macOS Ventura any time I clicked a link in Teams, Safari would become active and open the link. Now when I click a link Safari opens the page but does not become the active window. I have to manually switch to Safari to see the page I opened. Is there a way to revert this behavior so Safari automatically becomes active?

This behavior occurs when opening a link from Teams, not when opening a new tab within Safari. I have the following option enabled and it does not fix the issue I have described:

[image: option toggled on]

Having this toggle on does switch focus to the new tab or window when Safari is already the active focus application, but it does not cause Safari to gain active focus when Teams is currently in focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari CMD+Click link new tab focus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162866/safari-cmdclick-link-new-tab-focus)

Comment: No, this is not regarding opening a new tab - rather I am asking about opening a link altogether. It's the Safari window that's not gaining focus at all, not just the new tab. I have that option enabled already.

Comment: The answer references both *and* and windows regarding focus.

Comment: I have the option enabled but Safari does not gain focus when I click on a link in an external application.

Comment: Does the menu bar show Safari in focus, yet not the specific window? Do you have Safari on more than one Space? Do you have some windows minimised? Also, confirm the state of the switch "When switching to an application…" In Mission Control prefs - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gECQ9.jpg [pref will probably be in a different place in Ventura, as they appear to have moved everything… just for fun]

Comment: Thank you for the questions Tetsujin. The menu bar does not show Safari in focus, the menu bar focus stays on whichever application the link was clicked from. I do not have any windows minimized and only use a single Space, so there are no other Safari instances. I have turned on the "When switching" Mission Control setting you have linked, but it does not change the behavior I have described.

Comment: Update: I have noticed this is only occurring with Teams, not all external applications. I will edit the original question to add this information.

Comment: Thank you for the extra info; that's helpful. Unfortunately I know nothing of Teams, but I wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks anyway, and I'm actually very glad to hear that you know nothing of Teams and hope that never changes :D